# How to override sort mechanism of TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, indexing, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset

Is it possible to change the way indexes are used in `TClientDataSet` to sort records? After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257746/custom-sort-method-in-delphi-to-sort-list-of-strings), I thought it would be nice to be able to sort string fields *logically* in a client dataset. But I have no idea how to override default behavior of client dataset when it comes to indexes. Any ideas?

PS: My CDS is not linked to any provider. I'm looking for a way to modify the sort mechanism of the `TClientDataSet` (or the parent in which the mechanism is implemented) itself.

Comment: Are you displaying data from CDS to the user? If so, which component are you using? Most Grid- and ListView-type components allow you to implement custom sorting so, if CDS doesn't have what you need, you can try using this instead.

Comment: @LightBulb I'm using JvDBGrid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot override the sort mechanism of a ClientDataSet - unless you rewrite the according part of Midas.

To achieve the correct sorting (whatever *logical* means) you can introduce a new field and set its values in a way so that, sorted with the standard mechanism, they will give the required sort order.

Comment: Is midas.obj source available? I'm more than willing to change the according parts of it if the source is available and the license agreement allows modifications to it.

Comment: c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\source\data\dsnap\midas\

Comment: I don't have the mentioned folder in my XE2 installation folder. :-(

Comment: The midas sources are included since D2010 in Professional and higher. If you have not fiddled with the setup it should be installed.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling my XE2

Comment: Found it. Midas source code is installed if you choose to install C++ Builder

Answer (score 3):

Read the excellent on-line article [Understanding ClientDataSet](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056) Indexes by [Cary Jensen](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/aboutcj.html).

It explains how to use various ways of sorting and indexing using [IndexDefs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.IndexDefs), [IndexFieldNames](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.IndexFieldNames) and [IndexName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.IndexName).

**Edit**: reply to your comment.

You cannot override a sorting method in [TClientDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet), but you can add do this:

If you want to do custom sorting on anything else than existing fields, then you have to add a [Calculated Field](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Calculating_Fields), perform a kind of order calculation in the [OnCalcFields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet.OnCalcFields) event, then add that field to the `IndexDefs`.

Comment: I've read the article. I'm looking to override the actual method which compares and positions records according to current index. Something like http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStringList.CustomSort

Comment: I have another question regarding using calculated fields and indexes. I have been unable to use internal calculated fields in an index so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896329/how-to-sort-a-clientdataset-on-a-calculated-field?rq=1

Comment: Hmm, that is too bad. I thought I'd done something like this in the past, but I don't remember the project any more. Sorry for that. Can you upload a small (code only) example to something like https://gist.github.com/ then I might be able to look into this later this week. Post a comment here when you uploaded the example.

Comment: I have a project running with a fkInternalCalc field and IndexName set to that. It doesn't work for fkCalculated fields, because those are not seen by the midas implementation, which handles the index.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to achieve the desired sort with an SQL statement that feed the ClientDataSet.

For example if I was dealing with the following strings in FieldN

```
a_1
a_20
a_10
a_2
```

and I wanted them sorted like this (I assume this is similar to what you mean by *logically*

```
a_1
a_2
a_10
a_20
```

then I would write the SQL as

```
SELECT     FieldA, 
           FieldB, 
           ... ,
           FieldN,
           CAST(SUBSTRING(FieldN, 3, 2) TO INTEGER) As FieldM '<== pseudocode
FROM       TableA
ORDER BY   FieldM
```

The exact syntax of the SubString and Cast to Integer operations will depend on which DBMS you're using.

Comment: My CDS is an _in memory_ dataset.

Comment: All data on a computer is in memory, what's so special about your CDS? :-)

Comment: A ClientDataSet cannot execute SQL.

Comment: @UweRaabe I know that! I was suggesting he use an SQL to `feed` the CDS. I think there are some query components that have a built-in CDS. Anyway, the OP seems quite determined to solve his exact question not necessarily the problem of logical sorting.

Comment: @Sam My CDS is filled with data coming from a serial port, not from a RDBMS

Comment: @iManBiglari oh ok. All the best.