Sorting by calculated field
I have a ADOStoredProc component bound to a DBGrid. In addition to the columns from the stored procedure, a calculated field has been created in Delphi.
Now there I need to implement sorting of the DBGrid precisely by this calculated field.
How can this be implemented using Delphi if it is not possible to change the stored procedure?

Some third-party grids allow pulling all the data in and doing sorting client side. As well a  client dataset can pull all the data and have its own indexes which can include calculated fields, ex (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896329/how-to-sort-a-clientdataset-on-a-calculated-field)

In order to define an index on a calculated field, the calculated field has to be defined as an internal calculated field (fkInternalCalc), not as a regular calculated field. An index can be added to the field once this is done.

One of the easiest way would be to load the TADODataSet returned into a TClientDataSet and run your TDataSource/grid off of that.
If you go this route, don't forget to include midas.dll or include MidasLib in your project.
